# ideas needed - cut the smb connection when disk full

Tags: windows, scripting, disk-space-utilization, perfmon

Hello sometimes we are having issues like when some misbehaving user copies files to a server via admin share or other share and he causes disk drive to fill and a p1 ticket be created by monitoring. I am thinking about ways to prevent this. I am not talking about file server with many user files, but any kind of windows server usually without FSRM role installed.

EDIT: so I played with FSRM quotas and set a custom quota for a root of a drive like this:
[image]
I have set hard quota and space limit to a disk capacity minus a few GBs. The effect is it immediately displays lower capacity of the drive in my computer (as seen in a picture) - the same as what I set in the quota limit. This effectively prevents any user activity from filling the drive over the set limit. I am not sure about services though - are they are also prevented from writing more data above the set limit?

```
wmic logicaldisk get name,size,freespace
```

this command however shows real quota unaffected values which is good because that means monitoring software will probably be unaffected by hard quota.

The PROBLEM IS that I does not seem possible to set hard quota for C:! It remains on soft even when I set hard. If this is not possible then I can't really use FSRM quotas to prevent C: drive filling as I imagined.

Comment: `I don't think quotas would help because they are not related to a current free space` so ... you want a ruleset based on ... what? percentage of free space? `some users don't use any disk space and others do lot, it would be a waste of space to try to figure out some effective and fair quotas.` a waste of space .. why?